# Hide dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on dropdownlist with c# asp.net and javascript, imma newbie at js and can't figure out which method should i use to hide controls i tried several codes on google like style.visibility = "none" (i'm using radio button as trigger )

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         function enbaleTextbox() {
             var txt1 = "<%=othersLeave.ClientID%>";

            if (document.getElementById("<%=rdbOthers.ClientID%>").checked == true) {

                document.getElementById(txt1).style.visibility = "inline";


            }

            else if(document.getElementById("<%=rdbSickLeave.ClientID%>").checked==true) {

                document.getElementById(txt1).style.visibility = "none";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("<%=rdbVacaLeave.ClientID%>").checked == true) {

                document.getElementById(txt1).style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            {

                document.getElementById(txt1).style.display = "none";

            }
         }
```

code in front

```
<asp:RadioButton  GroupName="group1" enabled="true" runat="server" ID="rdbOthers" Text="Others" OnCheckedChanged="rdbOthers_CheckedChanged" onclick="enbaleTextbox(this.Id)" AutoPostBack="false"  />
```

Comment: used either style.visibility = "hidden" or style.display="none"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jequery then use:

```
$("#IdOfYourDropdown").hide();
```

If you need in plain javascript

```
document.getElementById(IdOfYourDropdown).style.display = "none";
```

keep in mind if you use `style.visibility = "hidden"`, it will hide your control but will not shrink space.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```js
$("#yourselection").css("display","none")
```